# Symfony 3.3 can't save on update with Custom Validator

Tags: php, symfony, validation

Hi I've a custom validation that check unique value on two tables (that means I can't use `UniqueEntity` validation)

My code work fine except on update data. The validation see entity already have a data as a new one but, actually it's an update

The question is how to fix this bug

**And this is my code**

**KeywordsUnique.php**

```
class KeywordsUnique extends Constraint
{
    public $message = 'This {{value}} already used';

    /**
    * {@inheritdoc}
    */
    public function validatedBy()
    {
        return 'keyword_unique';
    }
}
```

**KeywordsUniqueValidator.php**

```
class KeywordsUniqueValidator extends ConstraintValidator
{
   /**
    * @var RepositoryInterface
    */
   public $keywordRepository;

   /**
    * @var RepositoryInterface
    */
   public $additionalKeywordRepository;

   public function __construct(
       RepositoryInterface $keywordRepository,
       RepositoryInterface $additionalKeywordRepository
   )
   {
       $this->keywordRepository = $keywordRepository;
       $this->additionalKeywordRepository = $additionalKeywordRepository;
   }

   /**
    * @param mixed $value
    * @param Constraint|KeywordsUnique $constraint
    */
   public function validate($value, Constraint $constraint)
   {
       if (!$value) {
           return;
       }

       /** @var KeywordInterface $keyword */
       $keyword = $this->keywordRepository->findOneBy(['word' => $value]);

       /** @var AdditionalKeywordInterface $additionalKeyword */
       $additionalKeyword = $this->additionalKeywordRepository->findOneBy(['word' => $value]);

       if ($keyword !== null) {
           if ($value === $keyword->getWord()) {
               $builder = $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message);
               $builder->addViolation();
           }
       }

       if ($additionalKeyword !== null) {
           if ($value === $additionalKeyword->getWord()) {
               $builder = $this->context->buildViolation($constraint->message);
               $builder->addViolation();
           }
       }
   }
}
```

Thank you for your advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Problem solve!**

The problem is the `manager` found the entity as a new one (The `manage` will detect automatic)

**How to fix this ?**

You must check `object` that pass in to validation by use `id` and check `value` by use `context` of `Constraint $constraint` to get object

like this code

```
$object = $this->context->getObject();

// Create data
if (null == $object->getId()) {
    -- enter code for check validation
}

// Update data
if ($object->getId() != null) {
    -- check value (if same data just return;) --
    -- if value has changed just enter code for check validation --
}
```

That's it !!